# Change International to Roman characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have a string with International characters on it, like "Çiñoën Stra­ße"

I need to code a function to change the string to a Roman version as "Cinoen Strabe"

I can follow a mapping approach, for example if 'Ç' is detected, replace it with 'C'

I wonder if there is a best approach, like using COLLATE

Comment: Sadly I'm afraid you're stuck with a good old replace function. If you have lots of data, a CLR function go a long way performance wise.

Comment: Collate might work for some characters depending on the target code page, but probably you'll need to iterate over each character and replace with a mapped equivalent.

Comment: Turning "Stra­ße" into "Strabe" would be highly surprising to most German users, I'd wager, who would be expecting "Strasse". In any case, neither of those substitutions is innately supported by a T-SQL function, though you can use `TRANSLATE` to build your own. If you're only doing it for comparison purposes, you can use an accent and/or case-insensitive collation, or a language-specific one for special cases (e.g. `select 1 where N'straße' = N'strasse' collate German_PhoneBook_100_CI_AI`).

Comment: Perhaps the fact you want to replace ß with b is a good case for that you *shouldn't* be doing this. Would you replace both ø and œ with o and oe respectively too?

Comment: you would maybe write strasse instead,. but strabe is absolutely wrong

Comment: Seems like the mapping approach is the way to go, thanks for your feedback

Comment: What do you plan to do with the U+00AD soft hyphen in the middle of `Straße`?

Answer (score 0):

this is more or less how it turned out

> SET @output = REPLACE(@output COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin, 'ß', 'ss')

> SET @output = REPLACE(REPLACE(@Output COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin, 'ç', 'c'), 'Ç', 'C')

Here it is the full list of European characters and their equivalent

https://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Special_symbols.html